# How to trigger pipeline by Azure create run pipelines API?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure data factory subscription, I want to trigger pipeline through my node.js application. The pipeline transfers data from azure cosmos to Azure blob storage. I have triggered the pipeline once manually. And I was trying to do the same with a node.js app, but it throws the following error:

```
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.0.2:8080
    at ClientRequest.onError (/home/deepti/Desktop/dbmanager/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

And here's my code in node.js app :

```
Request.post("POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelines/{pipelineName}/createRun?api-version=2018-06-01",(err,res,body)=>{
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
        });
```

Can anyone please guide me how do I rectify this error and proceed further. Do I need to generate some authorization token too?

Also, I actually want to back up data that is 1 month old from cosmos DB to Azure Blob, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Can anyone please guide me how do I rectify this error and proceed further. Do I need to generate some authorization token too?

Yes,before process of creating pipeline run , you need to generate Authorization token in Headers. You could refer to [ADAL nodejs sdk](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs#server-to-server-via-client-credentials) to generate token. If you don't know what are these parameters:

[image]

,then please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and this [blog](https://arjunphp.com/how-to-execute-azure-rest-apis-node-js/) to get concepts of them.
And please note that you also need to grant ADFpermission to your ad app.

[image]

[image]

Finally,you could call the [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun) REST api and provide auth token in the `header`.

> 2.Also, I actually want to back up data that is 1 month old from cosmos DB to Azure Blob, is that possible?

If you want to back up azure blob storage data,please refer to this [link](https://samcogan.com/backup-for-azure-blob-storage/).You could use AzCopy in the schedule to back up the data during the stage.